# How to draw the figure (annular disc) in Tikz/Pgf plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw the following figure using Tikz/pgf plot ?

[image]

I have tried he following code  and got the below figure:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw[solid] (0,-1) circle (1); 
    \draw[solid] (0,-1) circle (2);
     \path [draw=none, fill=blue, even odd rule, fill opacity = 0.5] (0,-1) circle (2) (0,-1) circle (1);
    \draw[solid, shift={(6 cm,1 cm)}] (2,-2) circle (1);
    \draw[solid, shift={(6 cm,1 cm)}] (2,-2) circle (2);

    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

But how to fill the 2nd annular region, how to draw the map `f`, how to draw the `text` A, B, A-B ??

Please help me to draw the first figure.

**Update:**

Using the following script by @Zarko,

```
\fbox{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    % circles
    \draw [fill=blue!50, even odd rule] 
    (0,0) ellipse[x radius = 3, y radius=2, rotate=20] circle[radius=1] node {$B$};
    \draw [fill=blue!50, even odd rule]
    (7,0) ellipse[x radius = 3, y radius=2, rotate=35] circle (1) node {$D$};
    % labels
    \path   (0,1.5) node {$A-B$}  
    (0,2) node[above] {$A$}
    (7,2.2) node[above] {$C$};
    % arrow
    \draw[->]   (1.5,0.5) -- node[pos=0.35,above] {$f$}  (7,0.5);
    \draw [-to,shorten >=-1pt,black, thick] (1.5,0.5) -- (7,0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
      }
```

[image]

But I need the points on the axes as well.

I use the following Latex package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\topmargin=0.02cm
\textwidth =  17cm
\textheight = 23cm
\baselineskip=11pt
%
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.01 pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.01 pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ }
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{citecolor=black}
\newtheorem{fig}{figure}[section]
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\newcommand\norm[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}[thm]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{rem}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\makeatletter
\begin{document} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% circles
\draw [fill=blue!50, even odd rule] 
    (0,0) circle (2) circle (1) node {$B$};
\draw [fill=blue!50, even odd rule]
    (6,0) circle (2) circle (1) node {$B$};
% labels
\path   (0,1.5) node {$A-B$}  
        (0,2) node[above] {$A$}
        (6,2) node[above] {$A$};
% arrow
\draw[->]   (1.5,0.5) -- node[pos=0.35,above] {$f$}  (6,0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
with ellipses and changed shapes' labels:

```m
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% circles
\draw [fill=blue!50, even odd rule] 
    (0,0) ellipse[x radius = 3, y radius=2, rotate=15] circle[radius=1] node {$B$};
\draw [fill=blue!50, even odd rule]
    (7,0) ellipse[x radius = 3, y radius=2, rotate=30] circle (1) node {$D$};
% labels
\path   (0,1.5) node {$A-B$}  
        (0,2) node[above] {$A$}
        (7,2.2) node[above] {$C$};
% arrow
\draw[->]   (1.5,0.5) -- node[pos=0.35,above] {$f$}  (7,0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% circles
\draw [fill=blue!50, even odd rule] 
    (0,0) ellipse[x radius = 3, y radius=2, rotate=15] circle[radius=1] node {$B$};
\draw [fill=blue!50, even odd rule]
    (7,0) ellipse[x radius = 3, y radius=2, rotate=30] circle (1) node {$D$};
% labels
\path   (0,1.5) node {$A-B$}  
        (0,2) node[above] {$A$}
        (7,2.2) node[above] {$C$};
% arrow
\draw[->]   (1.5,0.5) -- node[pos=0.35,above] {$f$}  (7,0.5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted to achieve the first drawing at the top, so the second right ring should be filled too. :D

Comment: @Alenanno, you are right. I will corrected answer asap.

Comment: @Zarko, thanks. I have few questions: (1) how to replace the outside circle by an ellipse?  (2) how to replace the right hand side texts `A` and `B` by `C` and `D` respectively ?

Comment: @Zarko, Thank you very much. Finally how to box the whole figure in `box axis` frame? `\begin{axis} ---\end{axis}` is not giving the result ? I think we need to arrange the coordinates and labels

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR, you are not ending story :-(! You should be more clear in at writing of your question! Try to insert image in the `\fbox` (using `standalone` document class you need to add option `preview` to it}

Comment: @Zarko, sorry,I mean i just want to put the whole figure into an axis box. That is it.Thanks for your patience for tolerating me. I can't use `standalone`, I use `amsart`.

Comment: @Zarko, Please see my updated question. Using `\fbox{}`, I am getting the box but no `pointing` on the axes. I need to `pointing` as well

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR, sorry, where are your axes? I don't see any!

Comment: @Zarko, using `\fbox{ }`, I got that picture. But there are no points or no `x`-axis , `y-axis` mentioned  on the axes

Answer (score 3):

I propose this short code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
 \begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-1.6)(8,2)
    \psset{unit=0.8cm, fillcolor = ForestGreen!70,fillstyle = solid}
    \SpecialCoor\small 
    $ \multirput(0,0)(8,0){2}{\psRing(0,0){1}{2}\rput(0,0){B}\rput(0.5,2.4){A}}
    \rput{30}(1.45;140){A-B}
    \psset{labelsep=2pt, shortput=nab, npos=0.4, arrowinset=0.12}
    \pnodes{A}(1.4,0.5)(7.8,0.5)\ncline{->}{A0}{A1}^{f} $
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I use `\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{amsart}`. I tried your code but not compatible with my`document class. ` Any help?

Comment: Why not compatible with the class?

Comment: I am not sure but I tried and failed. May be my latex package is old. You can see in my edited question, the latex package which i am using.

Comment: Ì guess it is aproblem of compiling engine: pstricks doesn't work with pdflatex (this engine cannot make the calculations required by postscript), so you have to either  follow the traditional way: `latex ->dvips->pstopdf`, or compile with `xelatex`, which has no problem.

Comment: ok,thank you very much.I will try